# python regular about Chinese

Tags: python, regex

I am learning python and try to use regular expression to get some data from a html, and i am in trouble. This is my code:

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import urllib2
import re

url = u'http://www.6vhao.net/dy1/'
msg = u'ssss<a href="http://www.6vhao.net/dy1/index_2.html">下一页</a>&nbsp;<a'
pattern = re.compile(ur'\<a href="(?P<url>.*)"\>下一页</a\>')

response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = response.read()
#print html
for m in pattern.finditer(msg):
    s = m.group('url')
    print 'msg: '+s

for m in pattern.finditer(html):
    s = m.group('url')
    print 'html: '+s
```

the 'msg' in code is the data I want to get from the html.
But the output only "msg: http://www.6vhao.net/dy1/index_2.html".
I want to know why the regular expression does not work in html and how to make it work.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to decode the result from `.read()` to a Unicode object first:

```
html = response.read().decode("utf-8")
```